# react native vector icons not showing when not connected with metro in expo bare worflow

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

**react native vector icons not showing when not connected with metro in expo bare worflow**

**These are all my dependencies**

```
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^13.1.1",
    "expo-file-system": "^14.0.0",
    "expo-media-library": "^14.1.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "^4.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "^6.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
```

[Expected Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFcyV.jpg)
[Getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihnaJ.jpg)

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: No progress on this question.

Comment: my hunch here is you might not be able to run `react-native-vector-icons` with expo rather try installing via expo i.e. `expo install @expo/vector-icons`. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Install Following link on your project

```
npm i react-native-vector-icons
```

for more information see below document [click hear](https://%60%5Bhttps://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons%5D%5B1%5D%60)

and still not show than link react-native-vector-icons

Comment: I tried deleting react-native-vector-icons and reinstalling it didn't work I also tried deleting and reinstalling node_modules it still didn't work. I also tried react-native link react-native-vector-icons and also tried manual linking still no use